# Cant start preferenceActivity from Menu

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-preferences

I have created a class called Menu. In it when the user presses the menu button, they are presented with 3 options ie. about, preferences and exit. When they click preferences, a preference acivity is supposed to be opened. However, the app is crashing and failing to open the preference activity. I have posted the ListActivity, the activity tag for the activity I am trying to open in the manifest and the logfile. Please help.

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {
    String[] list = { "StartView", "FunWithText", "Email", "Camera",
            "ActivityStarter" };

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        try {
            Class myClass = Class.forName("com.thenewboston.terry."
                    + list[position]);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, myClass);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater balloon = getMenuInflater();
        balloon.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case (R.id.about):
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, Dialogue.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            break;
        case (R.id.preferences):
            Intent prefs = new Intent(Menu.this, Preferences.class);
            startActivity(prefs);
            break;
        case (R.id.exit):
            finish();
            break;

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

---

**Manifest.xml:**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Preferences"
        android:label="Start Activity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >



        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.thenewboston.terry.PREFS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

**Error Log:**

```
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thenewboston.terry/com.thenewboston.terry.Preferences}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class listPreference
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class listPreference
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:441)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:251)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:262)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.thenewboston.terry.Preferences.onCreate(Preferences.java:12)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  ... 11 more
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.preference.listPreference in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.thenewboston.terry-1.apk]
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:375)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
07-18 00:39:07.133: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  ... 19 more
```

> ```
> **Preferences xml:**
>
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <PreferenceScreen
>   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>   <PreferenceCategory android:title="Label">    
>     <EditTextPreference 
>     android:title="EditText"
>     android:key="name"
>     android:summary="Enter your name"/>
>
>     <CheckBoxPreference
>     android:title="checkBox"
>     android:key="music"
>     android:defaultValue="true"
>     android:summary="music on?"
>     />
>     <listPreference
>     android:title="list"
>     android:key="list"
>     android:summary="Choose somethign"
>     android:entries="@array/list"
>     android:entryValues="@array/values"
>    />
>   </PreferenceCategory>
>  </PreferenceScreen>
> ```

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }

}
```

Comment: select your lines of code and then press CTRL + K.

Comment: Also read the [Markdown formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Looks to me your error comes from the `Preferences` class and/or its `XML` layout file.

Comment: Thanks for explaining... I had asked how to format my post the because someone had done it form me.

Comment: added preferences xml and Preferences class. Please help :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the theme applied to the PreferenceActivity was not compatible with a PreferenceActivity object. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your Preferences.xml needs to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <PreferenceCategory android:title="Label">    
    <EditTextPreference 
    android:title="EditText"
    android:key="name"
    android:summary="Enter your name"/>

    <CheckBoxPreference
    android:title="checkBox"
    android:key="music"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:summary="music on?"
    />
    <ListPreference
    android:title="list"
    android:key="list"
    android:summary="Choose somethign"
    android:entries="@array/list"
    android:entryValues="@array/values"
   />
  </PreferenceCategory>
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: tried that and it didnt work. Have adjusted my input to reflect it. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: It is "ListPreference" not "listPreference". Sorry for not spotting it earlier.